# What are the advantages of DB2 over VSAM?

Tags: db2, vsam

What are the advantages of [DB2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_DB2) over [VSAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Storage_Access_Method)?

Comment: Here you can find a good comparison artical between two: http://www.tatasafariclub.com/post-94008.html for the advantages of db2 over VSAM look here : http://search400.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid3_gci1072318,00.html

Comment: Here is a list of points which explain [why DB2 is better than VSAM](http://search400.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid3_gci1072318,00.html). I hope it helps. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Links take you to nice explanations, but it boils down to DB2 offering referential integrity and ability to use SQL.  In addition to that DB2 supports things like procedures, views, and triggers.  DB2 understands relationships between tables.  In z/OS implementations DB2 tables are actually stored as linear VSAM files.

Answer (score 0):

- **VSAM** : file system, so no concurrent updates, no logging, no back-outing
- **DB2**  : database : concurrent updating with logging and back-outing